# replacing all images from a class with another image using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, src, getelementsbyclassname

I'm using an external script on my website with a form.
Some of the css is customizable, but I can't change images for example.
I would like to replace the small image displayed when a field is not completed by an other one using Javascript.

This is the HTML code with the original image :

```
<img class="incorrect-img" count="1" src="http://www.detailsdetails.eu/images/newimg/incorrect.gif"></img>
```

I'm trying with this Js code but it's not working...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

document.getElementsByClassName("incorrect-img").src="MYIMAGE.gif";

});
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Maybe it's because I'm trying to change an image from a class, maybe it only works with ID ? I can't change the class by ID...

Comment: i think `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array

Comment: If you have jQuery which `$(document).ready()` looks like, then this is easier with jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName("incorrect-img")` returns an `HTMLcollection` which is like an array but not quite.

Luckily you can loop over it like you would with an array:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("incorrect-img");
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i+= 1) {
    elems[i].src = "MYIMAGE.gif";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( ".incorrect-img" ).each(function( index ) {
        $(this).attr('src', 'MYIMAGE.gif');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using jQuery, instead of:

`document.getElementsByClassName("incorrect-img").src="MYIMAGE.gif";`

You can use:

`$(".incorrect-img").attr("src", "MYIMAGE.gif");`

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns the elements of array which are matched with class selector, In your case there is  only one image so `0` index would be fine for access the first element. like this

```
document.getElementsByClassName("incorrect-img")[0].src="MYIMAGE.gif";
```

For inormationa about [`getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName)

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot.
I combined your answers.
here is my final code :

```
$(window).load(function() {

var image = $(".incorrect-img");
for (var i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
image[i].src="incorrect_2.gif";
}

});
```