# Some of images does not change after calling the getElementsByClassName function

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbyclassname

In my app after switch on the dark mode function, I want some of my images to change to others. But it does not happen when the image is made of two pictures, and then the rest of the images after this does not change too [here is image that clearly describes the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hrt5h.png).

And this is the PHP and javascript code:

```php
    <?php } else if ($rating_avg > 4.75 && $rating_avg < 6) { ?>
        <form class="star-form" action="star_frame.php?post_id=<?= $post_id ?>" method="POST">
            <div class='stars_avg_div' align='center'>


                <i class='star1' id='star1' style='width:20px; height:20px; '><img class='star1img' src='starou.png' style='width:20px; height:20px;background-color:gold; '></i>


                <i class='star2' id='star2' style='width:20px; height:20px; '><img class='star2img' src='starou.png' style='width:20px; height:20px;background-color:gold;'></i>


                <i class='star3' id='star3' style='width:20px; height:20px; '><img class='star3img' src='starou.png' style='width:20px; height:20px;background-color:gold;'></i>


                <i class='star4' id='star4' style='width:20px; height:20px; '><img class='star4img' src='starou.png' style='width:20px; height:20px;background-color:gold;'></i>


                <i class='star5' id='star5' style='width:20px; height:20px; '><img class='star5img' src='starou.png' style='width:20px; height:20px;background-color:gold;'></i>

            </div>
        </form>
    <?php } ?>

    function darkmode() {
            $('*').addClass('dark');
            $('avg_iframe').addClass('dark');

            localStorage.setItem('mode', 'dark');


            document.getElementsByClassName("star1img")[0].src = "starou_dark.png";
            document.getElementsByClassName("star2img")[0].src = "starou_dark.png";
            document.getElementsByClassName("star3img")[0].src = "starou_dark.png";
            document.getElementsByClassName("star4img")[0].src = "starou_dark.png";
            document.getElementsByClassName("star5img")[0].src = "starou_dark.png";

            document.getElementById("half_star_1")[0].src = "starou_half_1_dark.png";
            document.getElementById("half_star_2")[0].src = "starou_half_2_dark.png";

        }
```

While the page is loading, the console panel shows error

> "TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefined 
>         star_avg_frame.php:88:22 (reference to last lines of code)"

I tried also `getElementsByIdName` instead `getElementsByClassName`, but that was not it. Have you an idea why the situation shown on the image takes place? I must add, that if there are no "half stars", all work well.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: look this, they had the same problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783594/replacing-all-images-from-a-class-with-another-image-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `querySelector(".star1img")` instead of `getElementsByClassName` and you get first element with `class="star1img"`

And `document.getElementById("half_star_1")[0].src = "starou_half_1_dark.png"` makes no sense, because with `getElementById` you get 1 element, not array. So you don't need to use [0] after it. Also you don't have elements with this id on page

Comment: I tried to do it with queryselector instead of getelementsbyclassname, as you said, but after it the problem (white background of image) spreaded on the rest of stars and now all backgrounds are white